# swagger doesn't recognize api description

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I instatiate `docket` like this

```
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .select()
        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.config.internal"))
        .paths(Predicates.or(PathSelectors.ant("/api**/**")))
        .build();
}
```

I created a set of stub endpoints that imitate the real one for `/login` or `/oauth`.

```
@Api("Authentication")
@RequestMapping("/api")
public interface LoginEndpointApi {

    @ApiOperation(value = "Github SSO endpoint", notes = "Endpoint for Github SSO authentication")
    @ApiResponses({
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "HTML page of main application")
    })
    @GetMapping("/oauth/github")
    default void oauthGithub() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @ApiOperation(value = "Get CSRF token", notes = "Returns current CSRF token")
    @ApiResponses({
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "CSRF token response", response = String.class,
            examples = @Example({@ExampleProperty(value = "015275eb-293d-4ce9-ba07-ff5e1c348092")}))
    })
    @GetMapping("/csrf-token")
    default void csrfToken() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @ApiOperation(value = "Login endpoint", notes = "Login endpoint for authorization")
    @ApiResponses({
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successful authentication")
    })
    @PostMapping("/login")
    default void login(
            @ApiParam(required = true, name = "login", value = "login body")
            @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

But it doesn't recognize it. It is located in the same `com.config.internal` package as I described.

But the page `swagger ui` is empty and shows that `No operations defined in spec!`

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide swagger documentation for your request mappings specified above you could simply describe it with `.paths(Predicates.or(PathSelectors.ant("/api/**")))` path matchers. But if your path includes something more complicated like `api + text without backslash separator` then you should get known with
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't see those request mappings at all

Comment: Try `return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any()).paths(PathSelectors.any()).build();`